# Get time from offset which is in hours and minutes format javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting the timezone offset in the following manner. "530" or "-800".

This indicates that the time is ahead of GMT by 5 hours 30 minutes or behind gmt by 8 hours. How can I get data-time given this offset.

I am using this snippet to get the date-time given the exact offset. Offset equivalent to "530" is 5.5

```
d = new Date();
utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
```

nd gives the date time object. The offset here = 5.5

How do I calculate that offset equivalent of "530" is 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

Use the remainder operator to extract the minutes, the rest is easy:

```
var offsetInput = "530";
var minutes = offsetInput % 100; // 530 % 100 = 30
var hours = (offsetInput - minutes) / 100; // 500 / 100 = 5
var offset = hours + minutes/60; // 5 + 30/60 = 5 + 0.5 = 5.5
```